# Login with User-Agent as token

Tags: php, mongodb, fat-free-framework

I'm working on a website project **(PHP, Fat-Free and mongodb)** and I have a problem with only one user.

When the user does login, I call this function:

```
function login() {

    $user = F3::get('POST.user');
    $pass = F3::get('POST.pass');

    if($user!=""&&$pass!=""){

        $bcrypt = new Bcrypt(12);

        $ismail = strrpos($user, "@");

        $loginUser = new HT('user');


        if($ismail===false){
            $loginUser->load(array('nick' => $user));
        }else{
            $loginUser->load(array('email' => strtolower($user)));
        }

        if(!$loginUser->dry()){
            if($loginUser->isActive == true){
                $isValid = $bcrypt->verify($pass, $loginUser->password);  
                if($isValid){

                    $final_token = StringHelper::rand_str(30);

                    $tmp = $loginUser->token;

                    if(!is_array($tmp))
                        $tmp = array();

                    $cli_id = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);


                    $tmp[$cli_id] = $final_token;

                    $loginUser->token = $tmp;

                    $user_id = $loginUser->_id."";

                    $loginUser->loginDate = new MongoDate();

                    $loginUser->updateFromId();

                    $isPremium = $loginUser->isPremium;

                    F3::set('user_id', $user_id);


                    if(isset($loginUser->preferences) && isset($loginUser->preferences['langPref'])){
                        $lang = $loginUser->preferences['langPref'];
                        echo json_encode(array("status"=>"OK","id"=>"$user_id","token"=>"$final_token","langPref"=>"$lang","schema"=>"$schema","isPremium"=>$isPremium));
                    }else{
                        echo json_encode(array("status"=>"OK","id"=>"$user_id","token"=>"$final_token","langPref"=>"en","schema"=>"$schema","isPremium"=>$isPremium));
                    }

                }else{
                    echo json_encode(array("status"=>self::NOT_EXIST));
                }
             }else{
                echo json_encode(array("status"=>self::NOT_ACTIVE));
             }
        }else{
            echo json_encode(array("status"=>self::NOT_EXIST));
        }

    }

}
```

**NOTE:** dry() function checks if user is null in mongodb.

The user says that in his office computer can't do login, and he gets and "Invalid password" error. But he can login in the website in any other computer.
Sometimes, if he deletes cache or reset his password can access to the website.

I'm saving in the 'User' mongodb collection an array of tokens like this:

```
{
 ........ (Other params),
 "token" : {
    "d222b6a854d35c9c9584e695b623c468" : "nX0CuAraUQMGm5UsUWhUqZzgXZnapN",
    "8c27b0d66a7ea6cec5dda9979cc92bd3" : "swdYhSQN5el0x9Pmn2YXZuwckpmuHP",
    "28b825f204e7ebd320756bd6294a29c1" : "UFGd18db8W9gq1WDXgx4F9BZRVRY3K"
 }
}
```

This token array contains: 
**key:** MD5 encrypted User-Agent
**value:** Random string

This keeps session for different devices and browsers.

Everytime the user wants to do something in the web I put in the route the user id and the token (value), and I check if values are correct:

```
....    
$uid = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

if(isset($user->token[$uid]) && $user->token[$uid]==$token){
 ....
 return true;
}else{
 return false;
}
```

I thought that the problem was with the User-Agent. Any solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the logic that brings back the message "Invalid password"? Also: http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/13523/45543

Comment: Is there a reason for not using [PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)? Relying on user agent for authentication looks like a terrible idea: 1) user-agent is not unique 2) it can easily be spoofed. If you don't want to change the whole logic, you could at least include the user IP into the md5 hash. With a little bit of luck, that could even maybe fix that issue you have (if that user has the same user-agent on both machines or no user-agent at all).

Comment: @xfra35 The project was already set up when I joined it... So I don't know why it is not using PHP sessions. I will try with the user IP. Thanks!

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ The logic of "Invalid password" message is that I return the status: 'NOT_EXIST". I show the user custom messages according to the status received.